# Determine Which Domain is More Commonly Entered (WWW)

Tags: web, dns, google-analytics, subdomain, analytics

Is there a way (be it with Analytics, or etc.) to determine which version of my domain is entered more frequently? (**domain.com OR www.domain.com**)

I've yet to find a way to determine this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess viewing hostnames sorted by top visits would answer that question (unless you are explicitly stripping the www via filters).

[Here is an example](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Ahostname&metrics=ga%253Avisits&sort=-ga%253Avisits&start-date=2013-01-01&end-date=2013-05-03&max-results=50).